# Solve the system of equations $x+y+z=1, x y z=1,|x|=|y|=|z|=1, x, y, z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Solve the system of equations $x+y+z=1, x y z=1,|x|=|y|=|z|=1, x, y, z \in \mathbb{C}$

---

I tried with polar representation, letting $x=\exp{(ia)}$,$y=\exp{(ib)}$, $z=\exp{(ic)}$, with this I got $a+b+c=2 \pi n$, so the three numbers are essentially three points on a unit circle, with their centroid being the point $1/3$. But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: $i, -i,1$ is an answer

Comment: From first expression, we can say $$\sin A + \sin B + \sin C = 0$$ From $xyz=1...(ii)$, we can say $$\sin(A+B+C)=0$$ After dividing (i) by (ii),we get $$ \sin (A+B)+sin(B+C)+sin(C+A)=0$$. I found all these. Maybe these will be helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use $xy= 1/z = \overline{z}$ and similar to conclude that $xy+xz+yz = \overline{x+y+z} = 1$. Then $x, y, z$ are the solutions of the cubic equation $t^3 - (x+y+z)t^2 + (xy+xz+yz)t - xyz=0$, hence of $t^3-t^2+t-1=0$. That equation can be written as  $(t-1)(t^2+1)=0$, hence the solutions are $i$, $-i$, and $1$.

Comment: Why are  $x,y,$z
  the solutions of the cubic equation $t^3−(x+y+z)t^2+(xy+xz+yz)t−xyz=0$?

Comment: @pie Because the LHS factors as $(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)$

Comment: @pie because if $(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)=0$ then you'll end up with the given equation

Comment: @CatalinZara Wow, that is very clever.

Comment: Awesome solution. I got to your part by a rather bit complex process. I totally forgot about taking complement of the whole thing . +1

Answer (score 0):

If $x,y,z$ are distinct then $x+y+z=1$ means that the orthocenter is $1$ and lies on the circumcircle.

Hence the triangle is a right angled triangle with one of its vertices coinciding with $1$.

So if $x=1$ we have $y+z=0$ and $yz=1$ so that the other two variables are $i,-i$